# Geopackage in QGIS: Search and replace in all attribute fields at once

Tags: qgis, csv, geopackage, string, replace

**The context**

I have a Geopackage file opened in QGIS. It was created by importing a CSV file. However, when importing, something regarding encoding went wrong: I have several special characters like Umlauts (Ä, Ö, Ü) that are not correctly recognized (like `Ã„` for `Ä`). A possibility would be to fix this in the innitial CSV file and reimport. However, I already made several changes in the attributes, so I don't want to repeat the whole work.

**The question**

How can I search/replace all string fields in the attribute table to replace the relevant characters?

---

**What I tried**

What works is doing it on a filed-per-field basis, using Field calculator with this expression:

```
replace("fieldname", '[character to be replaces]', '[replace with character]')
```

As I have a lot of fields, I would like to to it for all fields at once. Exporting the attributes as CSV, changing it there and reimport is a risk as I don't want to create new confusions with delimiters, special characters etc. The data is assembled from different sources and this is no 100% consistent, so I already spent a lot of time harmonizing the data. Reimport a CSV is always tricky to be sure to have all fields in the right field data formats, defining the correct delimiters etc.

Comment: Do you have a list of all characters to replace?

Comment: Yes, I do havecsuch a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [refactor fields](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/it/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#qgisrefactorfields) algorithm and the expression:

```
replace("field1", map('ò','o','H','h','w','W','à','a','ì','i','ee','EE'))
```

changing the attribute name `field1`,`field2` etc ... and adjusting the characters to find and replace.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=list%20expression#replace

[image]

Comment: But if you have more attributes, like 20, it could be long to refactor all of them…

Comment: the 20 attributes would appear automatically, you just need to copy and paste the same expression 20 times!

Comment: And change field1, field2, etc in each formulas!

Comment: This is possible using `attributes()`: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#attributes

Answer (score 5):

If you dont mind using a little PyQGIS. As usual when working `with edit(layer)` code, make a backup before experimenting.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
# Define replacements: First one is the character to replace and second one to be replaced by
replacements = {
    "a": "B",
    "Ã„": "Ä`",
    "8%": "ü",
    "hello":"goodbye"
    }
with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        for field in feat.fields():
            if field.type() == 10: # if string
                fieldvalue = feat[field.name()]
                for k,v in replacements.items():
                    fieldvalue = fieldvalue.replace(k,v)
                layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), layer.fields().indexOf(field.name()), fieldvalue) # why isnt there a field.index() method????
```